# MVC3 editor template for IEnumerable doesn't generate 'for' attribute in @Html.LabelFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper, mvc-editor-templates

I have custom EditorTemplate for my `ViewModel` class (it generates a checkbox list).

In view my model is `IEnumerable<ViewModel>`, but when I call `@Html.EditorForModel()` in generated HTML `for` attribute of `label` tag is empty.

Everything works fine when I want to render only one checkbox.

```
public class StateViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

EditorTemplate:

```
@model Mcs.Sibs.UI.Web.Models.StateViewModel

@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
<div>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Checked)
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Checked, Model.Name)
</div>
```

My View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Mcs.Sibs.UI.Web.Models.StateViewModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm()
{    
    @Html.EditorForModel()
}
```

Generated HTML looks like this (for one checkbox):

```
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="[0].Id" data-val-required="The Id field is    required." data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val="true">
<div>
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="[0].Checked" data-val-required="The Checked   field is required." data-val="true">
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="[0].Checked">
<label for="">Checkbox label</label>
```

You can see that 'for' attribute is empty.
Am I doing something wrong or this is some kind of bug in MVC3 default `EditorTemplate` for `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: Hmm this is odd.  I assume you tried calling LabelFor without the second parameter as well?

Comment: @John - yes, I've tried without second parameter, still empty.

Comment: Yeah... I can't wait to see what the answer to this is.  Did you try doing a loop on your IEnumerable and then Html.EditorFor(model => Model[i])?

Comment: This will generate 'for' attribute, but then 'name' attributes won't be in form '[0].Checked' and when posting form data, model binder simply can't bind IEnumerable<T> parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and after about an hour of non-working solutions I solved using an additional ViewModel to wrap the IEnumerable collection.

Please try the following code:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<StateViewModel> StateViewModels { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Mcs.Sibs.UI.Web.Models.MyViewModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm()
{    
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.StateViewModels)
}
```

The id and for attributes will be correctly generated.
Of course you can adapt the names of the models to your naming conventions :)